# "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments" in LINQ expression with split string entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, webapi

```
var list1 = _context.Employees.Where(x=> x.EmployeeId.Equals(empId)
                    && **x.deptIds.Split(",")**.ToList().Any(p => (p!=(deptId.ToString()))));
```

Where, x.deptIds is department ids stored as string separated by comma.
Getting erro "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments". How to solve it?

Comment: Don't store multiple values in fields to begin with. This violates the most basic design rule. Client-side code like `String.Split` can't be translated to SQL

Comment: But this is already stored. Can't change the table design right this time. Any alternative code/solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search a varchar field, using LINQ, to build a list of recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824677/how-to-search-a-varchar-field-using-linq-to-build-a-list-of-recommendations)

Comment: Since you're looking by EmployeeId, my first guess is that you only have one such row in the Employees table, so just get the entire row with `_context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeId == empId)`

Comment: @GSerg, It has a solution. But it doesn't a good approach since one of solution is taking .ToList() in database object and then performing other filter operations. This causes response time is too high.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I'm not looking only for employee id. There is a field deptIds containing string of department ids separated by comma. I just want to filter employee ids those not in the dept id I passed to this function.

Comment: If you pass in all the parameters to `Split`, e.g. `Split(",", 99, StringSplitOptions.None)` you will get rid of this error and likely get another - unable to translate to SQL.

Comment: BTW, your code shown does not match your commented goal - your code will show employees that are not _only_ in the passed in dept id - is that what you meant?

Comment: @NetMage, Why it doesn't match? I just filter using empid and deptid in which deptid string need not contain passed deptid.

Comment: You say "those not in the dept id I passed" - so you pass in dept 12. The employee has `deptIds` = "1,2,12" which I assume means they are in dept 12, but because you used `Any`, this employee will be in `list1`. The only employees excluded will be the ones that have `deptIds` = "12" exactly, and are not in any other depts.

Comment: BTW, you need to update your question with the additional information you left out that are in the comments.

Answer (score 18):

Just specify an optional parameter. `string.Split(",")` becomes `string.Split(",", System.StringSplitOptions.None)`

providing optional parameters to string.Split resolved my error

Answer (score 1):

As the comments pointed out, storing multiple values in a field is a very bad design choice, so noone should ever get to the point when they have to use `String.Split` in a Linq.

But to answer your question, you can use `String.Contains`, `String.StarsWith` and `String.EndsWith`, these can be translated to SQL. For example you can write:

```
var list1 = _context.Employees.Where(x=> x.EmployeeId.Equals(empId)
    && (x.deptIds.Contains("," + deptId.ToString() + ",") 
        || x.deptIds.StartsWith(deptId.ToString() + ",") 
        || x.deptIds.EndsWith("," + deptId.ToString()
    ));
```

This solution can change depending on where you have spaces around the commas in the database.